# Quartz - schedule jobs every two Weeks on several Day of week and time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cron, quartz-scheduler

I need to create Job that will :

- starts one 12/20/2012
- endDate = 12/31/2017
- will occur every 2 weeks on Sunday and monday
- fires at 5 pm.

is this cron expression valid?

```
Date start = 12/20/2012;
Date endDate = 12/31/2017;
SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger()
    .withIdentity("trigger3", "group1")
    .startAt(startDate) 
    .withSchedule(cronSchedule("* * 17 0 0/2 *,SUN,MON").build())
    .endAt(endDate)
    .build;
```

Please advise.

Comment: I think * * 17 0 0/2 *,SUN,MON

Comment: To setup a cron job to occur at 5pm every Sunday and Monday would be  0 17 * * 0,1  where 0 = minutes, 17 = hours, * = day of month, * = month, 0,1= Sunday,Monday or day of week with Sunday as 0 and Saturday as 7.
I can't think of how to set every two weeks with this. I don't think the day of month and day of week can be used at the same time. That may not be true.

Comment: Were you able to figure this one out? Did you use any other tool to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, that you make a unit test based on your cron expression. With kudos to [Van de Voorde Toni](http://www.devexp.eu/2009/08/18/quartz-test-a-cron-expression/), you can base it on this code, and use it to verify that the "nextValidTimeAfter" matches your expectation:

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.quartz.CronExpression;

public class CronTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        final String expression = "* * 17 0 0/2 *,SUN,MON";
        final CronExpression cronExpression = new CronExpression(expression);

        final Date nextValidDate1 = cronExpression.getNextValidTimeAfter(new Date());
        final Date nextValidDate2 = cronExpression.getNextValidTimeAfter(nextValidDate1);

        System.out.println(nextValidDate1);
        System.out.println(nextValidDate2);

    }
}
```

Comment: this cron expression is invalid. try it out at cronMaker.com